# Regex to match first number only if the string starts with 3 numbers in a row

Tags: java, regex

I have to make a regex which selects the first number only if there are 3 numbers in a row in the beginning of the string.

Example:

```
012 test
```

Here I'd like to match the 0 at the beginning of the string.

```
02 test
```

Here I want nothing to be matched by the regex.

I have no idea how to check the string without matching it using regex. Is this possible?

Comment: Use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: You can use: `^(\d)(?=\d{2}\b)`

Comment: Thank you @anubhava, working perfectly.

Comment: @Sebastian Proske, never heard of those lookaheads, guess I'll spend some time to learn more about them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check which follows two digits and [start anchor(`^`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to start at the beginning of the string.

```
/^\d(?=\d{2})/
```

---

**UPDATE :** You can use [word boundary(`\b`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to avoid matching when it follows any word character after the two digits.

```
/^\d(?=\d{2}\b)/
```

Comment: Thanks! Working perfectly!

Comment: This will also match when string is `123xyz` You should add word boundary in lookahead